# Keras Conv2D custom kernel initialization

Tags: python, keras, conv-neural-network

I need to initialize custom Conv2D kernels with weights

> W = a1b1 + a2b2 + ... + anbn

where W = custom weight of Conv2D layer to initialise with

a = random weight Tensors as `keras.backend.variable(np.random.uniform())`, shape=(64, 1, 10)

b = fixed basis filters defined as `keras.backend.constant(...)`, shape=(10, 11, 11)

> W = K.sum(a[:, :, :, None, None] * b[None, None, :, :, :], axis=2)  #shape=(64, 1, 11, 11)

I want my model to update the 'W' values with only changing the 'a's while keeping the 'b's constant.

I pass the custom 'W's as

> Conv2D(64, kernel_size=(11, 11), activation='relu', kernel_initializer=kernel_init_L1)(img)

where `kernel_init_L1` returns `keras.backend.variable(K.reshape(w_L1, (11, 11, 1, 64)))`

`Problem:`
I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. Is it possible to specify in Keras which ones are `trainable` and which are not. I know that layers can be set  `trainable = True` but i am not sure about weights.

I think the implementation is incorrect because I get similar results from my model with or without the custom initializations.

It would be immensely helpful if someone can point out any mistakes in my approach or provide a way to verify it.

Comment: But, does my approach mean that only the 'a' values are updated? How do I verify this?

Comment: Then how can I control which parameters are updated in Keras? How can I stop the 'b' values from changing, so that the changes in 'W' are only due to change in 'a'.

Comment: As far as I know, only layers can be set `trainable=False`

Comment: I thought about it again, and I removed my previous comments. You're right, only "layers" can be trainable/untrainable. To control what are weights, you must create a custom layer and implement a custom "build" method.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Warning about your shapes: If your kernel size is `(11,11)`, and assuming you have 64 input channels and 1 output channel, your final kernel shape must be `(11,11,64,1)`.

You should probably be going for `a[None,None]` and `b[:,:,:,None,None]`.

```
class CustomConv2D(Conv2D):

    def __init__(self, filters, kernel_size, kernelB = None, **kwargs):
        super(CustomConv2D, self).__init__(filters, kernel_size,**kwargs)
        self.kernelB = kernelB

    def build(self, input_shape):
        
       
        #use the input_shape to calculate the shapes of A and B
        #if needed, pay attention to the "data_format" used. 

        #this is an actual weight, because it uses `self.add_weight`   
        self.kernelA = self.add_weight(
                  shape=shape_of_kernel_A + (1,1), #or (1,1) + shape_of_A
                  initializer='glorot_uniform', #or select another
                  name='kernelA',
                  regularizer=self.kernel_regularizer,
                  constraint=self.kernel_constraint)

        
        #this is an ordinary var that will participate in the calculation
            #not a weight, not updated
        if self.kernelB is None:
            self.kernelB = K.constant(....) 
            #use the shape already containing the new axes


        #in the original conv layer, this property would be the actual kernel,
        #now it's just a var that will be used in the original's "call" method 
        self.kernel = K.sum(self.kernelA * self.kernelB, axis=2)  
        #important: the resulting shape should be:
            #(kernelSizeX, kernelSizeY, input_channels, output_channels)   


        #the following are remains of the original code for "build" in Conv2D
        #use_bias is True by default
        if self.use_bias:
            self.bias = self.add_weight(shape=(self.filters,),
                                    initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                    name='bias',
                                    regularizer=self.bias_regularizer,
                                    constraint=self.bias_constraint)
        else:
            self.bias = None
        # Set input spec.
        self.input_spec = InputSpec(ndim=self.rank + 2,
                                axes={channel_axis: input_dim})
        self.built = True
```

---

### Hints for custom layers

When you create a custom layer from zero (derived from `Layer`), you should have these methods:

- `__init__(self, ... parameters ...)` - this is the creator, it's called when you create a new instance of your layer. Here, you store the values the user passed as parameters. (In a Conv2D, the init would have the "filters", "kernel_size", etc.)
- `build(self, input_shape)` - this is where you should create the weights (all learnable vars are created here, based on the input shape)
- `compute_output_shape(self,input_shape)` - here you return the output shape based on the input shape
- `call(self,inputs)` - Here you perform the actual layer calculations

Since we're not creating this layer from zero, but deriving it from `Conv2D`, everything is ready, all we did was to "change" the build method and replace what would be considered the kernel of the Conv2D layer.

More on custom layers: https://keras.io/layers/writing-your-own-keras-layers/

The `call` method for conv layers is [here in `class _Conv(Layer):`](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/blob/master/keras/layers/convolutional.py#L152).

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will try this out. :)

Comment: could you also give me some advice about the `call()` function? This is my first time implementing a custom Keras layer. Do I need to implement the Conv2D functionality or somehow call the Conv2D layer function?

Comment: No, that's all you need. See the updates in the answer.

Comment: Thanks for the update; really helped a lot. 2 more questions though:
1. I use the layer as 
`l1 = CustConv2D(filters=64, kernel_size=(11, 11), kernelA=None, kernelB=basis_L1, activation='relu')(img)` #img_shape = (28, 28, 1)

But I get output as `(None, 28, 28, 1)` instead of `(None, 18, 18, 1)`

2. I get `ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient.` when I train. How can I find which operation?

Comment: That would need another questoin with detailed code, your model and the custom layer... But you should not be passing "kernelA"

Comment: I have added a new question about the `ValueError` [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304703/keras-custom-layer-valueerror-an-operation-has-none-for-gradient)