# Custom keras layer raises : ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

So I'm trying to create my custom layer as such:

```
from keras.layers import Layer, Multiply, Add, Dot, add, Dense
import keras.backend as K
import numpy as np
from itertools import product
from keras.activations import relu
from time import time
import tensorflow as tf
from keras import initializers

class NoisyLayer(Dense):
    def __init__(self, units, **kwargs):
        self.units = units 
        super(NoisyLayer, self).__init__(units,**kwargs)

    def build(self, input_shape):
        self.state_shape = input_shape
        self.weight_mu = self.add_weight(name='weight_mu', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.units),
                                      initializer=self.kernel_initializer,
                                      trainable=True)
        self.weight_sigma = self.add_weight(name='weight_sigma', 
                                      shape=(input_shape[1], self.units),
                                      initializer=initializers.Constant(0.017),
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias_mu = self.add_weight(name='bias_mu', 
                                      shape=(self.units,),
                                      initializer=self.bias_initializer,
                                      trainable=True)
        self.bias_sigma = self.add_weight(name='bias_mu', 
                                      shape=(self.units,),
                                      initializer=initializers.Constant(0.017),
                                      trainable=True)

        super(NoisyLayer, self).build(input_shape)

    def call(self, input_tensor):

        WeightedInp = K.dot(input_tensor, 
                            self.weight_mu + self.weight_sigma)
        bias = self.bias_mu + self.bias_sigma
        return relu(K.bias_add(WeightedInp, bias))

    def compute_output_shape(self, input_shape):
        return (input_shape[0], self.units)
```

And I test it with this simple script:

```
from  NoisyLayer import NoisyLayer
from keras.models import Model
from keras.layers import Input
import numpy as np
from keras.optimizers import Adam

inp = Input(shape=[4])
out = NoisyLayer(units=2)(inp)

model = Model(inp, out)
model.compile(Adam(), loss='mse')

a = np.random.rand(4)
f = np.random.rand(2)

a = np.expand_dims(a, 0)
f = np.expand_dims(f, 0)

for step in range(10000):
     print("Alrighty: ", step)
     _ = model.fit(a,f)
```

which raises:

```
ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient. Please make sure that all of your ops have a gradient defined (i.e. are differentiable). Common ops without gradient: K.argmax, K.round, K.eval.
```

The ops are all simple and straight from keras so it doesn't make sense for them not to have gradients. Another thing I found is that this error also raises if I'm not using all the defined weights, but it also doens't make sense since I do.

So what is the error?

Answer (score 1):

Ok the answer is from here :
[Keras Custom Layer ValueError: An operation has `None` for gradient.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51304703/keras-custom-layer-valueerror-an-operation-has-none-for-gradient?rq=1)
As said there I'm destroying my build by calling:

```
super(NoisyLayer, self).build(input_shape)
```

inside the call function