# How to create a sliding 2d autoencoder in keras?

Tags: tensorflow, keras

I'm working on a toy Keras/Tensorflow project targeting the MNIST dataset. I want to build something akin to a 2D convolutional network, but instead of a stack of filters, I want to produce a dense vector representation.

Here is an example of a model that I used to create an autoencoder for a 3x3 sub-sample of the input:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Flatten(input_shape=(3, 3)))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(4, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(32, activation='elu'))
model.add(Dense(9, activation='sigmoid'))
model.add(Reshape((3, 3)))
```

Using this model, I know that the topology is close to what for my 3x3 kernel. What I am trying to figure out is how to replicate/tile the first three layers of this model over my 2D image. I would like to have all of the features of the Conv2d layer such as strides/padding but it's not clear to me if/how i could replace the kernel of that layer with an entire multi-layer "sub model".

Some properties that I would like:

1. The "kernel" needs to be shared across the tiled instances so that we only have to train a single kernel.
2. However we define this kernel, it would be nice if it could be expressed in keras layers
3. It has all of the sampling features of Conv2d like padding/strides/dilation

Some things I have tried:

- [Keras Conv2D custom kernel initialization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51265578/keras-conv2d-custom-kernel-initialization) - seems to require the kernel to be reduced to a single tensor?
- Using `K.tile` but that seems to require me to reimplement large parts of Conv2d and it's not clear if the variables that are created are shared or new instances

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're in luck, because there's a `tensorflow` function that does exactly what you want. You're looking for [`tf.image.extract_patches`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/image/extract_patches). You can just put it in a `tf.keras.layers.Lambda` layer to wrap it in a `tf.keras.layer.Layer`. A cleaner way to do it is `tf.keras.layers.Layer`, but it has slightly more effort. More info on how to do that can be found in the docs for [`tf.keras.layers.Lamba`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/layers/Lambda)

Comment: I'm going to accept this but also add that in TF 2.x the method is now called tf.image.extract_patches.